# Java: Why is int x and int y used in this code (Arrays in methods)

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently following a youtube tutorial for beginners at Java. It's currently showing me how to use arrays with different methods.

```
class apples {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int bucky[]={3,4,5,6,7};
    change(bucky);

    for(int y:bucky)
        System.out.println(y);

}

public static void change(int x[]){
    for(int counter=0;counter<x.length;counter++)
        x[counter]+=5;

}
```

}

More importantly the int x in the change method I do not know why it is used and the tutorial explained it very briefly.

Comment: In the `change()` method, the argument is an array of `int` values, not an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid confusions like this, the method should have been declared as follows:

```
public static void change(int[] x)
```

Both the form in the question and the above one are equivalent, but now it's clearer that the method receives an integer *array*, not just an integer. In other words: the `[]` part should be written after the type of the elements in the array, because the type of `x` is `int[]` : an array of integers. It should be easy to understand why we can call `change` with `bucky` as parameter:

```
change(bucky);
```

Just one line before, we said that `bucky` is an array of integers. Again, it's better if we write it like this:

```
int[] bucky = {3,4,5,6,7};
```

So `change()` expects an integer array as parameter, and that's exactly what we're passing.

Answer (score 1):

The `int[] x` is the parameter for the method `change`. When calling the method, an array must be passed in. In this case, `bucky` is the array that is passed into the method `change` with the line: `change(bucky);`.